# 'fsockopen(): unable to connect to :80' when saving global configuration

Tags: joomla-3.x, global-configuration

I have just transfered a web site to a new host using Akeeba. On the face of things it looks ok but when I try to change something in the global configuration, I get a blank page when saving.

I edite the configuration.php to enable more logging and get the following:

> Notice: Undefined index: SERVER_ADDR in
>   /mnt/webw/b2/78/56896778/htdocs/plugins/system/jSGCache/jSGCache.php
>   on line 176 Warning: fsockopen(): php_network_getaddresses:
>   getaddrinfo failed: node name or service name not known in
>   /mnt/webw/b2/78/56896778/htdocs/plugins/system/jSGCache/jSGCache.php
>   on line 183 Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to :80
>   (php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: node name or service
>   name not known) in
>   /mnt/webw/b2/78/56896778/htdocs/plugins/system/jSGCache/jSGCache.php
>   on line 183 Fatal error: Call to undefined function
>   php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: node name or service
>   name not known() in
>   /mnt/webw/b2/78/56896778/htdocs/plugins/system/jSGCache/jSGCache.php
>   on line 188

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Joomla backend, go to your Plugin Manager, and disable the Siteground Cache plugin.

Once done, try making and saving your changes in the Global Configuration.

As much as I love Siteground hosting, I'm not a big fan of their caching facilities.

Comment: When I try to disable the plugin I get a similar error message. Notice: Undefined index: SERVER_ADDR in /mnt/webw/b2/78/56896778/htdocs/plugins/system/jSGCache/jSGCache.php on line 176 Warning: fsockopen(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: node name or service name not known in /mnt/webw/b2/78/56896778/htdocs/plugins/system/jSGCache/jSGCache.php on line 183 Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to :80 (php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: node name or service name not known) in /mnt/webw/b2/78/56896778.....

Comment: Try disabling it via PhpMyAdmin in the `#__extensions` table

Comment: @paul - Glad it worked. If this answered your question, please mark the answer as accepted so others know it has been solved

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem but could not disable any extensions that I thought were causing the problem. I had to go into MySQL to disable it.

```
MariaDB [fe_joomla]> select extension_id, package_id, name, enabled, state from josld_extensions;
+--------------+------------+---------------------------------+---------+-------+
| extension_id | package_id | name                            | enabled | state |
+--------------+------------+---------------------------------+---------+-------+
|        11002 |          0 | System - jSGCache               |       1 |     0 |

MariaDB [fe_joomla]> update josld_extensions set enabled = 0 where extension_id = 11002;
```